# Regarding a PHP path in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been Working on a project in that project I am using single video on home page as slider in design everything is good but when we work on core php.Video is not showing because of in the design video comes using jquery with static path but in the development how to give php path in jquery and how to dynamically change this video from the back-end. I have done php path in jquery like (filename":" But it's not Working. please correct it.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var videobackground = new $.backgroundVideo($('.page-sec'), {
  "align": "centerXY",
  "width": 1280,
  "height": 720,
  "path": "uploads/",
**"filename":"<?php foreach($videos as $video){
   echo $path.$video['video'];**}  ?>",
   "types": ["mp4","ogg","webm"]
    });});
   </script>
```

Comment: never mix php with js - it's bad practice, languages were built separet for a reason :D

Comment: Can u tell me how to do it dynamically in php

Comment: you would create a hidden span, and assign a data- tag to be a string of the array contents as a csv (comma-separate value) then in js, call it using `.data()` and `split` it using ',' as a delimite

Comment: That's a little overboard, it's perfectly acceptable practice at the beginning of the script to just do something like `var myvar = '<?php echo $myvar; ?>'`, and then just call `myvar` within the function.

Comment: OP you are echoing `$path` in your php but you also have a `path` set in js,  are you sure you aren't doubling up like `uploads/uploads/`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var videoPathsString = $('#videoPaths').val();
                var videoPathsArray = videoPathsString.split(',');

                var videobackground = new $.backgroundVideo($('.page-sec'), {
                    "align": "centerXY",
                    "width": 1280,
                    "height": 720,
                    "path": "uploads/",
                    "filename": videoPathsArray,
                    "types": ["mp4", "ogg", "webm"]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $videoPaths = '';
        foreach ($videos as $video) {
            if ($videoPaths != '') {
                $videoPaths .= ',';
            }
            $videoPaths .= $path . $video['video'];
        }
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" id="videoPaths" name="videoPaths" value="<?php echo $videoPaths; ?>" />
    </body>
</html>
```